# Having issues setting up events

Tags: c#, events

In my class we are learning how to use events in c#. The professor wants us to set up events for our "Robot" player states. What I am trying to do is when I change the state f the Robot then I want that state to register to an event method. But I am having issues setting up the events. I get these errors

Error 1

```
Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PracticeWithEvents.Program.PlayerActions' and 'method group'
```

Error 2

```
Cannot convert method group 'OnIdleState' to non-delegate type 'PracticeWithEvents.Program.PlayerActions'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
```

I am relatively new to the whole registering for events so i am sure I am not doing this right. I looked online but I couldn't find anyone with my same problem. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code, hope it helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeWithEvents
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creating the states for the player
        /// </summary>
        public enum PlayerActions { IDLE, ATTACK, MOVE, DYING }
        /// <summary>
        /// creating our enum handler
        /// </summary>
        public static PlayerActions CurrentAction = PlayerActions.IDLE;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            switch (CurrentAction)
            {
                case PlayerActions.IDLE:
                    CurrentAction += OnIdleState;
                    break;
                case PlayerActions.ATTACK:

                    break;
                case PlayerActions.MOVE:

                    break;
                case PlayerActions.DYING:

                    break;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Logic for the Idle State
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">gets the event</param>
        void OnIdleState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IDLE");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Logic for the Attack State
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">gets the event</param>
        void OnAttackState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ATTACK");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Logic for the Move State
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">gets the event</param>
        void OnMoveState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MOVE");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Logic for the Dying State
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">gets the event</param>
        void OnDyingState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DYING");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CurrentAction` is not an event - it's just an `enum` property.  Read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) on adding events.  Hint: Step 1 is finding/defining a proper `EventArgs` class.

Comment: `PlayerActions` isn't an `event`, so you can't subscribe to it.

Comment: Typically you'd have a Class (Robot/Player?) that would declare the Event.  Something external to that class (the Main method) would then subscribe to those events.  You need to create an instance of that Robot/Player class and subscribe to events of that particular instance.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Also, what do you think your code will do once that `switch` is finished?

Comment: I had a very hard time to figure out how to put all this "event stuff" to work. The definitive text for me (which explained everything in a "for dummies" way) was [How to Implement Events in Your Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), from MSDN.

Comment: @DStanley There is no need to use `EventArgs` at all when dealing with events.  That's only a convention.  All that is needed for an event is a field of any delegate and the `event` keyword.

Comment: @DStanley Thank you very, very much! I did the research on adding events and now I have a good understating on what I need to get my project working. I'll have it done in no time. This really helped me out a lot. I wish I had more reputation to vote you up, cuz u earned it, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

The class that is going to send events must contain events of a certain type. The type of an event is defined by the signature of some delegate you have to define somewhere.

Then, the code using your class (or even some instance of the very class) will attach handlers to it. These handlers will run when the event fires. It is a sort of "inversion of control", when users of your class tell it: "here, I want you to run this code I am handing to you every time you trigger this event". That's where the `+=` syntax come from: you can attach more than one handler to a given instance's event.

Finally, depending on your needs, you can subclass `EventArgs` so that you can pass custom values or parameters every time the event fires, so that client code (the code which provided the handler) can get information about the event. Which information it is, depends on your intents.

Also, you seem to be confused about the difference between actions, events and states. These are what define the behavior of finite-state machines. State machines have a finite number of states. The change from a state to another is defined by events. Each state has one or more events which, when happen, deterministically cause a change to another well-defined state. Upon this, you can have enter actions and exit actions. And, AFAIK, you don't need a formal state machine to benefit from event-based programming.

It is a bit obscure, to me, how you can get from your current code to some working implementation of what I just wrote, but I guess you can figure it out. If not, [a much more complete explanation is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Hope this helps.